# How to remove extra space on right side with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I want to remove extra space on right side with ellipsis class.

```css
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
}
div{
    float:left;
}
.clear {
clear:both
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div><div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">asdasdasd</div><div>asdadsas</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: space after ellipsis !

Comment: I know its stupid but `max-width: 84px;` will do the trick, whereas `text-overflow: ellipsis;` consumes extra space while hiding the content with "..." .

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay thanks but text are dynamic

Comment: The 'extra space' is part of the ellipsis suffix. You cannot control the suffix added by defining `text-overflow: ellipsis;` thus your problem is unsolvable.

Comment: The extra space isn't there in Firefox, so the question is, why does Chrome insert the space there? Or more precisely, why does Chrome expand the floating div to its max-width? This smacks of a bug.

Comment: @MrLister the `extra-space` is in `FF` too, so its not an browser issue.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Hmmm, that's odd. Although I've got the same font in FF and Chrome, FF spaces the letters out just a fraction of a pixel more, so there's not nearly as much space after the ellipsis as in Chrome. But the div is indeed the same width in pixels, See [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LL7f5.png). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think that this can not be achieved without some nasty hardcoded workaround or an intuitive JS + ellipsis solution... If you are ok with introducing the JS to the problem I can help.

Comment: @akash: Does `.ellipsis { margin-right: -8px; }` not work for you? Otherwise there is no other way because this is implementation (browser vendor) dependent as specifications do not talk about it.

Comment: @Abhitalks thanks :)

Comment: 100% agree with @klaar this is unsolvable!!

Comment: @RohitKumar any trick ? or should i delete this question ?

Comment: others have suggested for negative margin-right, but that is not a good solution because where ... doesn't appears there also margin-right will be applied and content will appear bad. However, you can try _creating your custom `...` adding JS function_ for this instead using the default `text-overflow: elllipsis`, also I noticed a behavior of this, when you will add one by one 'a', then 'b' till 'd', in the very beginning `.ellipsis` text you will find that the space shrinks and then disappears, this is default behavior you cannot change this. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5c7re4wz/

Comment: In my case, setting not only `width`, but also `min-width`, helped with this issue.

Comment: This is not precisely white-space but has to do with how the browser computes ellipsis: It tries to render the whole text, thereby pushing the container to as big as it can and needs to be, 90px in your example. Then it realizes it still doesn't fit and ellipsis has to be used. It does that but it doesn't shrink the container anymore (probably because of performance). Now this means there is extra space up to the width of the first invisible character at the end. "up to" means it might also fit exactly. Which is why negative margin-rights are bad advice. I also consider the problem unsolvable.

Answer (score 2):

```
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
    float:left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both
}
<div class="ellipsis">Some Text</div><div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">Some Text</div><div>asdadsas</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
div:nth-child(2n){
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

and adjust the pixel until it matches (if u need it dynamic you can use em, % or vw/vh)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wyqs19gh/)

Nimmi

Comment: Wut ?! I added an Fiddle link there you can see it working.

Comment: i have checked your link but it's not working please check it

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this...

```css
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
    float:left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div><div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">asdasdasd</div><div>asdadsas</div>
```

Comment: Sorry... i am seeing same result

Comment: then how you exactly want ...may I know??

Comment: can you see some space after ellipsis "..." ?

Answer (score 0):

That depend on the `font-size` and the `font-family` in this case you should set `max-width:` to `87px`

Answer (score 0):

What about right signing text to the right?

```css
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div><div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">asdasdasd</div><div>asdadsas</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
}
div{
    float:left;
}
.clear {
clear:both
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">hsdhhgasdihgasdgj</div><div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">asdasdasd</div><div>asdadsas</div>
```

There will be no space after `ellipsis`. It defends on the char in the text. For example try changing your text to `hsdhhgasdihgasdgj` and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

for firefox instead of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

use  `text-overflow: ellipsis '...';`
or   `text-overflow: clip '...';`

for chrome it wont work  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133700

so use what i declared in `forchrome` class that would support for both, or detect the browser first and show html accordingly if you want to use text-overflow extra properties. In `forchrome` class just the change is that i have written `margin-right:-1px` to shift 1px from end of the string

```css
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 90px;
}
.elipdot {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis'...';
  max-width: 90px;
}
.elipclip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip'...';
  max-width: 90px;
}
.forchrome {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #930;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
div {
  float: left;
  /** for debugging**/
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<!-- previous code using default-->
<div class="ellipsis">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div>
<div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">asdasdasd</div>
<div>asdadsas</div>
<!-- will not work on chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133700
    <!-- using text-overflow: ellipsis '...'; -->
<div class="elipdot">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div>
<div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="elipdot">asdasdasd</div>
<div>asdadsas</div>
<!-- using text-overflow: clip '...'; -->
<div class="elipclip">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div>
<div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="elipclip">asdasdasd</div>
<div>asdadsas</div>
<!-- previous for chrome-->
<div class="forchrome">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div>
<div>asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="frochrome">asdasdasd</div>
<div>asdadsas</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your request you want the two lines length equals...

If so you can add the `letter-spacing` property to the class `ellipsis`

here an example
http://jsfiddle.net/c2o3pd2a/

Answer (score 0):

try the following style

```
.ellipsis {
   text-overflow:clip;
   max-width:100%;
}
```

let me know if it is helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can add `margin-right: -5px` to your elipsis class

```
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayv7352/2/)

Answer (score -1):

I created class `.space-off` which remove this space with `margin-left` help. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/70c8skup/) is example:

```css
.ellipsis {
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
    float:left;
}

.space-off {
    margin-left: -6px;
}

div {
    float:left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">hsdhhgasdhgasdgj</div>
<div class="space-off">asdasd</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ellipsis">asdasdasd</div><div>asdadsas</div>
```