# Remove extra space end of text overflow ellipsis on FF and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge

Similar to this thread: [How to remove extra space on right side with ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982401/how-to-remove-extra-space-on-right-side-with-ellipsis)
Extra space appears after "..." and in a small area the text appears not center-aligned. Wonder if there is any way to get rid of the tiny little extra space.

If give a bigger padding then visually it will be better, but then it is also sacrificing area to display the text.

Fiddler:
https://jsfiddle.net/rqzoad5h/

```
enter code here
```

Run the link on Chrome (Version 74), FF (v67), IE11 (v11.0.105) and Edge (v40.15063) 
Only Chrome "appears" to have the text center-aligned.

Comment: There's no space there? That's just where the input box ends.

Comment: Put the code in the question next time.... Stackoverflow has same ability as jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were to guess **(Tested only on FF)**

In Chrome when the text goes ellipsis, chrome considers the `"ellipsized"` text to be a whole new text and then centers it, which we can replicate.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.child1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">FD...</div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">FDDLE</div>
</div>
```

**The Only difference is the space between the dots which we can mimic with letter-spacing if we're too concerned**

FF however doesn't do that and considers the whole text as is, now the problem is that we want to replicate that extra care chrome does on other browsers, we can use some JS plugin that does this, or a much more practical solution

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.child1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">FD...</div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">FDDLE</div>
</div>
```

**Why`2px` on left and right ?**

Because it looks good after `2px`.

`div.child2` width is `36px` with after the padding the contents width becomes `36 - 4px(left) - 4px(right) = 28px` which leaves `28px` for the content to live in at this point chrome recenters the text basically adds a bit more than `2px` on each side to center it because of `text-align:center;` now FF and IE ignores that property and so let's center ourselves by adding those `2px` to left and right side, which will leave the content with `28px - 2px(left) - 2px(right) = 24px` `24px` to live in without the need to apply that as a `max-width` to make it dynamic/response

**DEMO: if the parent decided to grow(talking aboute a response design)**

```css
.parent {
  
  transform: translate(100px, 50px) scale(3); /* just to zoom in */
  
  
  position: relative;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  animation: grow 4s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    width: 36px;
  }
  to {
    width: 80px;
  }
}

.child1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 100%; /* make this take paren'ts width */
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">FDDLEWERSDF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is good analysis Zohir. Appreciated.

Comment: Pleasure, however I'm not entirely sure about it but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is how FF renders the page, and there is really nothing much that can be done.

You can try adding `.max-width` to `.child2`, and adjust its padding accordingly.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
.child1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.child2 {
   font-size: 10px;
   line-height: 20px;
   padding: 8px 6px; /*Changed 4px to 6px*/
   position: absolute;
  max-width: 24px; /*Added*/
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">FDDLE</div>
</div>
```